# Print the values generated by each child process in c

Tags: c, fork

I have forked a process n number of times to have n children. After forking, at some point, I need to generate a random number in each of the child processes and so I write a statement to do so. But before I proceed, I want to see the random number each of the children have generated on the terminal. When I write printf(), I just get one output which I believe is the random number that the parent generated. Can someone help me with how I can get all the child processes to print the value that the variable rnd_number holds in their address spaces?

Also, since each child would execute the statement calling them to print their rnd_number values, I wonder what made them not print in on the terminal. In case I am mixing some concepts up, I request someone to help me out here.

Answer (score 0):

You have to wait in the father for every child to finish. If it finish before its children, the children won't print anything.

About printf, don't forget that this function bufferize data, be wary of using '\n' for forcing printf's flush.
For knowing which child get what random, you want to print its pid using the getpid() function.

```
pid = fork();
switch (pid)
{
  case '0' : // Son
            srand(time(NULL)); // having one srand per process sounds better than doing it in the father
            int r = rand() % X; // put your randomizer here
            printf("Getting %d from %d \n", r, getpid());
            return r; //sending to father rand value
  case -1 : //Error
           perror("fork");
           exit(1);
  default : //father
          int status;
          wait(&status);
          printf("retriving %d from %d",WEXITSTATUS(status), pid ); 
}
```

Thats the code for a single process, but you got the idea. You just have to use a same fashion for your multiprocess program.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I, however, need to do this:
`for(i = 0; i<n; i++){
 pid = fork();
 if (pid==0) Do_something();
 else if (pid<0) report error;
 else Do_something_else();
}
/*Some logic that all the processes created so far have to execute*/
r = rand()%X;
print(r); //I want the print to give me the value of r from each of the processes forked.`
 If it helps, I have the PIDs of each of the processes created stored in an array

Comment: You can use the waitpid(); and loop on that with each pid stocked on your array. Is that helping you out ?

Comment: Unfortunately it does not help. Even if I wait on the pids of the children, the printf does not seem to output the data on the console. To ensure that the buffers are flushed, I also used fflush() too. The printf ends up printing the local value of the variable instead of the value calculated by the child process.

Comment: Read my code again.  You see that on the child, i return the value generated, then i print it on the father. Have you used the return values to print your value ?